# Linking Feature Classes between Two Different Map Frames so that Definition Queries in one Frame Apply to Another Frame

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, definition-query

In ArcGIS Pro 2.4.1, would like to determine whether it is possible to link two identical feature classes, where feature class 1-1 is in map frame 1-1 and feature class 1-2 is in map frame 1-2. The ultimate end goal would be that a definition query placed in feature class 1-1 would automatically apply to feature class 1-2, and vice versa.

I have attempted to simply copy paste and, as expected, this does not produce the desired result. I have also tried to find a setting within the feature class properties but nothing appears to relate to a function like this.